# Why is link underline appearing after clicking the link?

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag styled with 
`text-decoration: none`.

This has removed the underline from my links, which is what I want.

However after the link is clicked, little bits of the link underline appear under the spaces between the icons in the link.

I have something like this

```
<a ng-click="toggle(this)" style="text-decoration: none">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"  ng-if="!collapsed"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o" ng-if="!collapsed"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right"  ng-if="collapsed"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-folder-o" ng-if="collapsed"></i>
</a>
```

(Using font awesome icons)

The underline is appearing just under the blank space between the icons.

Is there any way to get rid of that link underline for once and for always?!

Comment: leave no space; try to have an open <a> and fill in the lines in there without spaces. <i class></i><i class></i> etcc.. see that helps.

Comment: It's `text-decoration` not `text-decoration-line`. `text-decoration-line` exists, but is supported by only FF.

Comment: I modified the question to use text-decoration, because it is exhibiting the same behavior

Answer (score 77, accepted):

That is because the default CSS values for links are declared by different browsers. A link has 4 official states.

- Normal
- Hover
- Active (On mouseclick)
- Visited
- (Focus)

In CSS you can declare the style for each of these. If you want the link not to display the text-decoration in these states:

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited, a:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Answer to your comment**

Yes, you can replace the a with a classname. For instance, you have a link with the class 'myLink'.

You can make the CSS:

```
.myLink, .myLink:hover, .myLink:active, .myLink:visited, .myLink:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do that with a class, so it does not effect all of my links?

Comment: @VictorGrazi Yes you can. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I had do add: "a:focus { text-decoration:none; }" in the CSS.

Comment: Good Lord! I believed Mozilla Firefox was the most advanced browser on the planet but just `a, a:hover` wouldn't work! I didn't bother to check whether it was `:focus` or `:active` that fixed it for me, I included both as a (supposed) cross-browser fix.

Comment: Ohh! and by the way, `a {text-decoration:none !important;}` does work well too but wanted to avoid it. I just wouldn't want to scuffle through my CSS after a couple months trying to figure out what happened to my anchor tags.

Answer (score 10):

The right way and you should cover this by adding the following css in your style sheet definition:

```
**Longer CSS Styling definition:** 

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

**Shorter CSS definition:**

a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

this will ensure no underlining in **all state of links** to be absolutely sure that there will not be underlining in any of the links on the page. You can also condense the styling definition in your css so the code isn't long and it's more efficient to control **style for all link behaviours** because it applies to all of the links on the page when you're defining **a**

if you want to style it for specific links you'd do the following:

```
a.nav:link    {text-decoration: none; }
a.nav:visited {text-decoration: none; }
a.nav:hover   {text-decoration: none; }
a.nav:active  {text-decoration: none; }

<a href="/" class="nav">styled links</a>.
```

or something completely different adding in colours, overline, font weight, size which are going to be different in each link state for that specific class.

```
a.external:link    {color: #0000ff; font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold; }
a.external:visited {color: #894f7b; font-weight: bold; }
a.external:hover   {text-decoration: overline; background-color: #003399; }
a.external:active  {color: red; }
```

Comment: I was not aware of the a:link selector and it bite me when using react-router and their Link component - could not get rid of that nasty underline. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong property... `text-decoration-line` is not meant for this.

> The text-decoration-line property specifies what type of line, if any, the decoration will have

Use `text-decoration: none` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
   a{text-decoration:none}
   a:visited{text-decoration:none}
</style>
```

Add a stylesheet to your project

Comment: When I specify this in a stylesheet, it does not work. However if I inline right into the anchor tag style="text-decoration: none" that works. Is there any way to get this to honor the stylesheet?

Comment: that's strange and it shouldn't happen. you may have the style sheet in the wrong place or too may repeated <a link style definition existing in your style definition or something may be overlapping your style all together. In a html document when you specify a css definition between <head> it should cover all the links on that particular html document.

Comment: No, I have many other styles in the stylesheet. It looks like I needed the hover pseudo class