# Underline on hyperlinks get displayed before the actual text is loaded

Tags: html, css, position, underline

I have a little problem in my CSS (or maybe it's Chrome) but it happens with `<a>` links, it's kind of hard to show you the problem without video but I'll try with screenshots:

Below is the screenshot of my index page: ([link](http://prntscr.com/7fvneo))

[image]

When I click on any `<a>` link, initially it appears like in the below screenshot: ([link](http://prntscr.com/7fvo2k)) and after approximately 0 to 2 seconds, the page appears normal (like in the first screenshot).

[image]

It's as though the underline appears before the text appears, so it's messed up and after a little moment it return good.

I couldn't manage to make a fiddle with multiple HTML pages and so took a [little video](http://vid.me/4NHb). You can see the bug happen at 0:07s, but in fact it happens everytime I click but because of how fast it is and how low the framerate of the video is you can't see it everytime.

Have you already experienced this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle?

Comment: I didn't manage to make a fiddle with multiple HTML page (first time i use it, sorry) so i took a little video : https://vid.me/4NHb
You can see the bug happen at 0:07s, but in fact it happens everytime i click but because of how fast it is and how low the framerate of the video is you can't see it everytime.

Comment: The video explains the problem, now its time to show us your code please. And try this as well  `a:visited{text-decoration:none}` on your css  . This SO seems to be ur case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989672/why-is-link-underline-appearing-after-clicking-the-link

Comment: It is good that you have given the screenshots and also created a video to illustrate your problem. However, it is still difficult to debug it without the actual code. A demo of your index page (with the minimal code required to reproduce the problem) should help debugging it. I suspect you are either using web fonts (or) are sending a font file along with your page which is why the underline shows up before the actual text. A fiddle would actually make things like these clear.