# Right-click makes text-decoration: underline

Tags: css

I have all anchor tags set to `text-decoration: none`.

Moreover, I have a rule saying (thanks to this good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989820/4551792))

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But anytime I right-click with the mouse on a link on the website I am building, for instance, to open the inspector element, the link turns **underlined**.

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] for us to work and troubleshoot with?

Comment: This is very open ended issue you have presented, might be a specificity issue ..

Comment: Try adding `a, a:link, a:hover`... See: http://www.westciv.com/style_master/hands_on_tutorial_sm/08.links.html

Comment: I've just resolved the problem adding the !important to the rule I provide in the question. I would like to give a code example but it affects all the anchors tags of the website and all of them have text-decoration set to none. Now the the problem is resolved, the question remains. In theory why would the right-click make the anchor underlined? Not on hover, is just when the right click is made.

Comment: @viery365  are you sure ? check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/1e62xcdc/1/

Comment: Thank you for all your comments!. Yes, the specificity maybe would be the reason - Thank you for remember it . I will check the link @jbrya029. Thank you!

Comment: because of specifity rules, the question is not how you underline on the right-click. The question is what else is affecting your link during a click? (left or right -> active) See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1e62xcdc/2/

Comment: Thank you very much @ochi. That's it! It was exactly what was happening The only difference is that I set a jQuery to delay the active state of some of the anchor tags and I lost control of it. Although is strange because nothing in the jQuery script was mentioning text-decoration: underline while active. But your comment elucidated me. Thank you so much. Problem resolved!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [CSS specifity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the question is not how you underline on the right-click.

The question is what else is affecting your link during a click? (left or right -> active)

From the sounds of it, you have something other CSS rule that is affecting your 
anchors.

See sample code below (where the issue is not present):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#wrapper a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span id='wrapper'>
   <a href="#">link</a>  
</span>
```

Comment: Although, I must say that what was happening was that with left-click the text was not underlined, only with right-click but I suppose the reason of the problem had to do with specificity as you are saying because the !important resolved everything. Thank you for your answer which can be useful for other people out there.

Comment: @viery365 in that case, it could be a more nuanced issue like adding/removing CSS classes or styles via JS or JQuery *only* during the right-click event.  As I mentioned in my initial comment, it is hard to troubleshoot without a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, I do understand of course:). Without the code is really difficult to see, but thank you for explaining that nuance situation. It can be useful for other people as well.